# find something in a string then print it in python

Tags: python, regex, snimpy

im sure this is simple but im not good with regexp or string manipulation and i want to learn :)

I have an output from a string I get using snimpy. it looks like this:

```
ARRIS DOCSIS 3.0 Touchstone WideBand Cable Modem <<HW_REV: 1; VENDOR: Arris Interactive, L.L.C.; BOOTR: 1.2.1.62; SW_REV: 7.3.123; MODEL: CM820A>>
```

I want to be able to look into that string and use that info in an if to then print some stuff. I want to see if the model is a CM820A and then check the firmware version SW_REV and if its not the right version I want to print the version else I move on to the next string i get from my loop.
host.sysDescr it what returns the above string. as of now I know how to find all the CM820A but then i get sloppy when I try to verify the firmware version.

```
sysdesc = host.sysDescr
if "CM820A" in str(sysdesc):        
    if "7.5.125" not in str(sysdesc):
        print("Modem CM820A " + modem + " at version " + version)
        print(" Sysdesc = " + sysdesc)
    if "7.5.125" in sysdesc:
        print ("Modem CM820A " + modem + " up to date")
```

Right now I am able to see if the CM820A has the right version easily but I can't print only the version of the bad modems. I was only able to print the whole string which contains a lot of useless info. I just want to print form that string the `SW_REV` value.

#### Question

I need help with how to do this then I will understand better and be able to rewrite this whole thing which I currently am using only to learn python but I want to put to practice for useful purposes.

Comment: instead of `if "7.5.125" in sysdesc:` use `else` clause.

Comment: If this is not the case, can you give the current input and output along with expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `split()` , you can split your string with a special character for example see the following :

```
>>> l= s.split(';')
['ARRIS DOCSIS 3.0 Touchstone WideBand Cable Modem <<HW_REV: 1', ' VENDOR: Arris Interactive, L.L.C.', ' BOOTR: 1.2.1.62', ' SW_REV: 7.3.123', ' MODEL: CM820A>>']

>>> for i in l :
...  if 'BOOTR' in i:
...   print i.split(':')
... 
[' BOOTR', ' 1.2.1.62']
```

So then you can get the second element easily with indexing !

Comment: @JasonKack you're well come , so if you find this answer helpful you can tell this to community by accept it or voting !

Answer (score 0):

This answer will simply explain how to retrieve your desired information.
You will need to perform multiple *splits* on your data.

First, I notice that your string's information is subdivided by semi-colons.
so:

```
description_list = sysdesc.split(";")
```

will create a list of your major sections. since the sysdesc string has a standard format, you can then access the proper substring:

```
sub_string = description_list[3]
```

now, split the substring with the colon:

```
revision_list = sub_string.split(":")
```

now, just reference:

```
revision_list[1]
```

whenever you want to print it.